# Filter lookup column value using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, lookup-column, json-formatting, powerapp

I have a custom list where in the **Title** column we have 1 to 100 numbers. This **Title** column we are using in the **Lookup column** in another list.

Now while using the **lookup column** list, all the 1 to 100 numbers are getting populated which is as usual. Now we want to control this data in the lookup column - let all numbers (1 to 100) be there in the source list **Title** column but while using that **Title** column in the **lookup column** in another list, we just want to display 50 to 100 numbers.

Using JSON or any other ways will it be doable?

Comment: You want to show only 50 to 100 items in lookup dropdown on list form?

Comment: Yes I want to show 50 to 100 numbers in the lookup dropdown list

Comment: I have added one workaround in updated answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible using SharePoint JSON formatting.

You have to [customize the list forms using Power apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form). Follow this:

1. Customize list forms using power apps
2. Go to lookup column combo box (dropdown) control
3. Use [Filter function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup) in "items" property of combo box (dropdown) control to filter lookup list items as per your requirements.
4. Publish the forms.

**Note**: This approach will work only for list forms. This will not work in Grid view (quick edit) of list. So, you might want to disable the grid view (quick edit) from list settings > advanced settings.

For more information, follow article: [Filtering Lookup Columns in SharePoint using Power Apps](https://regarding365.com/filtering-lookup-columns-in-sharepoint-using-power-apps-7b15767e1009)

---

**Update**:

1. Create a calculated column in lookup source list (say "CalcTitle") like:

   ```
   =IF(VALUE([Title])>49,[Title],"")
   ```
2. Then use "CalcTitle" in lookup column settings instead of "Title" column

**Parent list**:

[image]

**Lookup column settings**:

[image]

**Child list form**:

[image]

**Reference**: [How to filter lookup column based on another column from using specific criteria?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/how-to-filter-lookup-column-based-on-another-column-from-using/m-p/3640553)